# Why am I getting a seg fault with my if statement?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I want to read a file and count the words. I want it set up so I can use a command line or, if no file is entered on the command line, to trigger an if statement that will get the file name and read it, then count the words. It works if I type the file name in command line, however it seg faults if I don't use it. Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   char file[75];
   if (argc < 2)
   {
      cout << "Please enter the filename: ";
      cin >> file;
      strcpy(argv[1], file);
   }
   string content;
   ifstream inFile(argv[1]);
   int count = 0;
   while (inFile >> content)
      count++;
   inFile.close();
   display(count, argv);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is UB: `strcpy(argv[1], file);`

Comment: If `argc` is less than 2 then what are the valid indexes for `argv`?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to break into the code after it segmentation faulted? What did that tell you? Learning to use a debugger is very good practice. You should try it even after you get an answer here, to make sure you see how you could have figured this out for yourself in the future.

Comment: I would suggest using `file` as your filename string, instead of `argv[1]`.  If `argc >= 2`, then load `argv[1]` into `file`; otherwise, read into `file` from `std::cin`.  Then, pass `inFile`'s constructor `file` instead of `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

You should not modify data of `argv` especially out of bounds. You logic should work opposite:

```
   char file[75];
   if (argc < 2)
   {
      cout << "Please enter the filename: ";
      cin >> file;
   } else
      strcpy( file, argv[1] );
   string content;
   ifstream inFile(file);
```

but you better use `std::string` for variable `file` as well.

Also `cin >>` inputs only words (excluding space symbols) but filenames can have them, so you better use `cin.getline( file )` or `std::getline( cin, file )` if you change `file` to `std::string`

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If the condition is true that is if `argc` is indeed less than 2 then in general case `argc` is equal to 1 and according to the C Standard `argv[argc]` is equal to `NULL`.

So the program in this case has undefined behavior.

In any case it is a bad idea to copy a string to argv[n] where n is some index because the source string can be larger than the target string.

You could use a reverse approach that is to copy `argv[1]` to `file`.